# Merging sheets in to a master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I got the following code from Ron de Bruin's site and it works pretty much fine for pulling data into a master sheet, and updating the master sheet whenever there are changes in the other sheets.

But I would like to copy only certain columns of data. For example my sheets have data from `A:Z` but i only need the `A:P` data in my master sheet.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated and please know that im a non-coder, so please be specific about what to change and where to change it.

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim shLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Delete the sheet "Master Sheet" if it exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet with the name "Master Sheet"
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Master Sheet"

'Fill in the start row
StartRow = 2

'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
    'Copy header row, change the range if you use more columns
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(DestSh.UsedRange) = 0 Then
  sh.Range("A1:Z1").Copy DestSh.Range("A1")
End If

        'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        shLast = LastRow(sh)

        'If sh is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow copy the CopyRng
        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

            'Set the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look below example 1 on this page
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If

    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to change the code that defines the area that should be copied. In your case you have to check the "ranges" before copying the data:

```
sh.Range("A1:Z1").Copy DestSh.Range("A1")
```

That line takes care of the headlines, so you can replace the Z1 with e. g. P1.

The next range is to copy the data:

```
Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
```

Here you can use the existing functionality to get the correct start row and last row. But instead of selecting the complete rows you will just select a part of the sheet:

```
sh.Range("A" & StartRow & ":P" & shLast)
```

That should do the trick.

P. S. Even If you are not a programmer. Have a look at the VBA Basics, its not that hard and you can do a lot of cool stuff if you know how it works... :)